# How to put and post links with Spring HATEOAS

Tags: java, spring, rest, hateoas, spring-hateoas

I'm trying to understand how to create and modify links in Spring HATEOAS.

For example, say I have two collections, one at api/users and another at api/event. I would like to associate a user api/user/56 with an event api/event/21. For arguments sake this is a many-to-many - a user may attend many events, an event may have many users.

As I understand it, the restful way of doing this is to use the URIs as primary keys, so I might post the following to api/user/56/events;

```
{
    attends: "http://localhost:9090/api/event/21"
}
```

The endpoint then needs to be able to parse that URL and extract the ID (in this case 21) and the controller (EventController.class) so that I can persist this.

Question 1: Is this the correct way of dealing with relationships in Spring Hateoas in terms of the REST API?

Question 2: How can I resolve this url in a controller to a usable handle on the data (for example a reference to the appropriate controller/method, a primary key, etc)

**Research**

RestTemplate can be used to request the data from the controller inside the request mapped method, like so;

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
ResponseEntity<EventResource> response = restTemplate.getForEntity(attendsUrl, EventResource.class);
EventResource eventResource = response.getBody();
```

However I don't believe that eventResource should return an Id field as part of the data - it's not very restful and this would be exposed on the API. One approach is to have a parameter "includePK=true" but again this doesn't feel right - it's just hiding the problem. Moreover the idea of the server making requests to it's own API in this manner seems circuitous.

**Update**

There is an open question for this here https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hateoas/issues/292. Based loosely on some of the comments (by user [kevinconaway](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hateoas/issues/292#issuecomment-131196790)) from that issue I have made a quick util class that offers an easy solution here: [SpringHateoasUtils](https://github.com/ununbium/SpringHateoasUtils). The solution boils down to;

```
String mapping = DISCOVERER.getMapping(targetClass, targetMethod);
UriTemplate template = new UriTemplate(mapping);
//values is key/value map of parameters that the referenced method accepts
Map<String, String> values = uriTemplate.match(uri);
```

[SpringHateoasUtils](https://github.com/ununbium/SpringHateoasUtils) makes this slightly nicer but it still feels like it should be a feature. I'll seek to get something in the spring code for this - when it's clear what is happening with this I'll answer this question.

Comment: You would post `http://localhost:9090/api/event/21` only. Spring HATEOAS doesn't help you to dereference a URL. It's only meant for responses, not requests. You might take a look at [Spring Data REST](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-rest/)

Comment: Having worked with Spring HATEOAS for several months it definitely does not appear to support REST properly, so I have had to implement similar workarounds to what you are describing.

Answer (score 4):

Look at the answer here:

[POSTing a @OneToMany sub-resource association in Spring Data REST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25311978/posting-a-onetomany-sub-resource-association-in-spring-data-rest?rq=1)

Question 1) Yes this is how you post links/relations. With  URIs.

Question 2) The URI of the resource actually **IS** its ID from the client's perspective.    The server internally automatically resolves this URI into the actual model instance with

`org.springframework.data.rest.core.UriToEntityConverter.convert(...)`

Comment: This is a question about Spring Hateoas - although Spring Data Rest allows for limited use of links, Spring Data Rest falls short of providing a way of implementing ones own link handling functionality.

Comment: Hello Andrew!  Did you have look at the link I posted? It also took me a while to understand the subtle differences. But meanwhile I found out how to archive what you are trying to do: Spring Data HATEOAS allows to "create" links between to entities  by posting   a text/uri-list  e.g. like this:  `curl -X PUT -H "ContentType: text/uri-list" http://localhost:8080/api/myEntitty/1`  with the link uri as payload `http://localhost:8080/api/myLinkedChildEntity/4711`     If you need more low-level access the you can always implement your own @RestController in spring rest