# How to add an object in a OneToMany relationship using Spring Data REST

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I cannot figure out how to add an object to a OneToMany relationship using Spring-Data REST when the mapped classes REST Repository is not exported.

I have two classes, `Question` and `Answer`. `Question` has a member variable defined like this:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "answer", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE) 
private List<Answer> answers = new LinkedList<Answer>();
```

And `Answer` maps back to `Question` like this:

```
@NotNull
@ManyToOne(targetEntity = Question.class)
@JoinColumn(name = "question_id", referencedColumnName = "id") 
private Question question;
```

Because `Answer` objects are only relevant to the `Question` they belong to, I've disabled exporting the REST repository:

```
@RestResource(exported = false)
public interface AnswerRepository extends JpaRepository<Answer, Long> {}
```

When I fetch a question here: `http://localhost:9090/data/questions/7`, I get something like this:

```
{
    "creationDate": "2014-09-26T06:36:44.000+0000",
    "modificationDate": "2014-09-26T06:36:44.000+0000",
    "answers": [],
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:9090/data/questions/7"
        }
    }
}
```

So far so good. Now I want to add an answer like this:

```
curl -v -X PUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -d "{"answers": [{"value": "Red"}]}" http://localhost:9090/data/questions/7
```

Unfortunately, at this point I get the following error:

> A collection with cascade=\"all-delete-orphan\" was no longer
>   referenced by the owning entity instance: com.example.Question.answers

A brief search of StackOverflow indicates the above error is caused by replacing your collection with another one, orphaning the previous collection. Since all of this code managed by Spring, I don't see how to manipulate my objects to avoid this problem.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25311978/posting-a-onetomany-sub-resource-association-in-spring-data-rest?rq=1) is similar, however the difference is that in this case the repository is not exported, while in that question it is.

Comment: I solved this problem by writing a custom controller to handle a POST to http://localhost:9090/data/questions/7/answers, but I don't consider that an answer to this SO question.

Comment: It shouldn't be necessary to implement your own controller. Your command doesn't add an answer, btw.

Comment: I agree it shouldn't be necessary, but I don't have another solution. Do you mean my comment doesn't add an answer? That's because I don't consider it an answer to the question.

Comment: Your command (= `curl ...`), not comment, doesn't add an `Answer` to a `Question`. If anything it replaces all answers. Posting to `localhost:9090/data/questions/7/answers` should work out of the box - have you tried it?

Comment: @zeroflagL - You are correct, the `curl` command I showed above is intended to set all answers, which I would expect to be a valid operation, but it doesn't work. Yes I tried POSTing to `...questions/7/answers`, that is what prompted this question. When you have `@RestResource(exported = false)` on your repository, it disables access to that URL and you get an HTTP 405 error.

Comment: I haven't tried 'rel', but I doubt it will help, according to the documentation it just modifies `answers` to whatever string you want. What I really want is to have the answer objects provided in the Question GET, and then be able to update them somehow. The REST way (`questions/7/answers`) would be fine, but I'll take anything.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `PUT` you [should be sending](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#_put_2) `text/uri-list` media type. But I don't see how would you do that since you did not export `Answer` repository thus you can not call `POST` on it first.

Did you try `PATCH`? It's not documented that way though...