# Spring HAL creating associated sub resource

Tags: spring, spring-hateoas, hal-json

Please check question [POSTing a @OneToMany sub-resource association in Spring Data REST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25311978/posting-a-onetomany-sub-resource-association-in-spring-data-rest)

Now the common sense says to me to create a new comment, I should be able to make a POST to for example http://localhost/posts/1/comments. And at the same time, I should also be able to retrieve all comments of a user via a search on http://localhost/comments/search/findByCommenter?commenter=XXX.

With spring, posting the way I mention is not supported. You need to PATCH. And as far as I know, thats only if you don't have a dedicated comment repository. So you can either PATCH a new comment to http://localhost/posts/1/comments if you don't have a comment repository, or you have to POST to http://localhost/comments if you want the searchability of comments by commenters. Whats the reason behind this?

Comment: Are these specific to Spring or HAL?