# Accessing and updating association resources with Spring Data REST and MongoDB

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb, spring-data-rest, spring-hateoas

I don't fully understand how creating and accessing association resources works with Spring Data REST and MongoDB. I have noticed a few strange behaviours, and I am hoping to get some clarification here.

I have a simple object model where one resource type (`Request`) contains a list of objects of another resource type (`Point`). Both resources are top-level resources, i.e. have their own `Repository` interfaces.

I would like to be able to add a new `Point` to a `Request` by POSTing to `/requests/{id}/points` with a link to an existing point (as I know from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25311978/posting-a-onetomany-sub-resource-association-in-spring-data-rest) that I can't just POST a point as a JSON payload).

Furthermore, I would like to be able to GET `/requests/{id}/points` to retrieve all the points associated with a request.

Here is my object model (getters/setters omitted):

*Request.java*

```
public class Request {

  @Id
  private String id;
  private String name;

  @DBRef
  private List<Point> points = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

*RequestRepository.java*

```
public interface RequestRepository extends MongoRepository<Request, String> {
}
```

*Point.java*

```
@Data
public class Point {

  @Id
  private String id;
  private String name;
}
```

*PointRepository.java*

```
public interface PointRepository extends MongoRepository<Point, String> {
}
```

Let's say that I POST a new `Request`. Then doing a GET on /requests gives me this:

```
{
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/requests",
      "templated" : false
    }
  },
  "_embedded" : {
    "requests" : [ {
      "name" : "request 1",
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" :     "http://localhost:8080/requests/55e5dc47b7605d55c7c361ba",
          "templated" : false
        },
        "request" : {
          "href" :     "http://localhost:8080/requests/55e5dc47b7605d55c7c361ba",
          "templated" : false
        },
        "points" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/requests/55e5dc47b7605d55c7c361ba/points",
          "templated" : false
        }
      }
    } ]
  }
}
```

So I have a `points` link in there. Good. Now, if I do a GET on `/requests/55e5dc47b7605d55c7c361ba`, I notice **strange thing #1**. There is no `points` link anymore:

```
{
  "name" : "request 1",
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/requests/55e5dc47b7605d55c7c361ba",
      "templated" : false
    },
    "request" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/requests/55e5dc47b7605d55c7c361ba",
      "templated" : false
    }
   }
}
```

But anyway forget about that for now, let's POST a point (which gets ID `55e5e225b76012c2e08f1e3e`) and link it to the request:

```
curl -X PUT -H "ContentType: text/uri-list" http://localhost:8080/requests/55e5dc47b7605d55c7c361ba/points
-d "http://localhost:8080/points/55e5e225b76012c2e08f1e3e"

204 No Content
```

That seemed to work. Ok, so now if I do a GET on `http://localhost:8080/requests/55e5dc47b7605d55c7c361ba/points`, I expect to see the point I just added, right? Enter **strange thing #2**, I get the following response:

```
{
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/requests/55e5dc47b7605d55c7c361ba/points",
      "templated" : false
    }
  }
}
```

So at this point I realise I've done something wrong. Could somebody please explain to me what's happening here? Do I have a fundamental misunderstanding of the way SDR is working? Should I even be using `DBRef`s? Or is this simply not possible with MongoDB?

Thanks in advance, and sorry for the long question!

### Edit

The `Point`s **are** in fact being added as `DBRef`s (verified by looking at the db manually), but it appears that SDR is not giving them back. If I explicitly ask for `http://localhost:8080/requests/55e5dc47b7605d55c7c361ba/points/55e5e225b76012c2e08f1e3e`, then I get the following response:

```
{
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/points/55e5e225b76012c2e08f1e3e",
      "templated" : false
    },
    "point" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/points/55e5e225b76012c2e08f1e3e",
      "templated" : false
    }
  }
}
```

Which is also strange... where is my `Point.name`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both aspects are caused by a [glitch in Spring Framework 4.2.0](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13318), which Spring Boot 1.3 M4 has upgraded to which causes Spring Data RESTs custom serializers not applied in some cases. This is already fixed in Spring 4.1.2. To upgrade your Gradle project to that version, upgrade to the Boot plugin to a 1.3 and then fix the Spring version to 4.2.1 using the following declaration:

```
ext['spring.version'] = '4.2.1.RELEASE'
```

Make sure you properly initialize the collection with an empty one as a `null` value will cause `404 Not Found` being returned. An empty list will produce correct HAL output.

Generally speaking association resources should be used with already existing resources, esp. with Spring Data MongoDB there's no other choice as it doesn't have persistence by reachability. I.e. you'd need to persist the related instance first (aka. `POST` to it's collection resource and get a `Location` header back) and the assign the just created resource (aka. `PUT` or `POST` the just obtained Location to the association resource), which seems to be what you're doing.

Comment: Hi Oliver, thanks for your response! Re #1, [here is the issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-664) with sample project linked. Re #2, I actually made a typo in the question. I am sending the URI in a `-d`. You should be able to reproduce it in the sample project. Not sure if it is a separate issue. P.S. SDR is awesome, keep up the good work!

Comment: Please see my edit, which may make it more obvious what is going on. FYI, I'm using `spring-data-rest-core:2.4.0.RC1` (gotten via `spring-boot-starter-data-rest:1.3.0.M4`).

Comment: Let's continue at the ticket for now. I'll update my answer once we got to a conclusion there :).

Comment: Updated after our findings.