# Using Spring Data REST to handle complex aggregate roots

Tags: spring, rest, spring-data-rest

Right now I can't get the concept behind Spring Data REST if it comes to complex aggregate roots. If I understand Domain Driven Design correctly (which is AFAIK the base principle for spring data?), you only expose aggregate roots through repositories.

Let's say I have two classes `Post` and `Comment`. Both are entities and Post has a `@OneToMany List<Comment> comments`.

Since `Post` is obviously the aggregate root I'd like to access it through a `PostRepository`. If I create `@RepositoryRestResource public interface PostRepository extends CrudRepository<Post, Long>` REST access to `Post` works fine.

Now `comments` is renderd inline and is not exposed as a sub resource like `/posts/{post}/comments`. This happens only if I introduce a `CommentRepository` (which I shouldn't do if I want to stick to DDD).

So how do you use Spring Data REST properly with complex domain objects? Let's say you have to check that all comments does not contain more than X characters alltogether. This would clearly be some invariant handled by the `Post` aggregate root. Where would you place the logic for `Post.addComment()`? How do you expose other classes as sub resources so I can access `/posts/{post}/comments/{comment}` without introducing unnecessary repositories?

Comment: Check out this post about dealing with aggregate objects: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25311978/posting-a-onetomany-sub-resource-association-in-spring-data-rest

Answer (score 2):

For starters, if there is some constraint on `Comment`, then I would put that constraint in the constructor call. That way, you don't depend on any external validation frameworks or mechanisms to enforce your requirements. If you are driven to setter-based solutions (such as via Jackson), then you can ALSO put those constraints in the setter.

This way, `Post` doesn't have to worry about enforcing constraints on `Comment`.

Additionally, if you use Spring Data REST and only define a `PostRepository`, since the lifecycle of the comments are jointly linked to the aggregate root `Post`, the flow should be:

1. Get a `Post` and its collection of `Comment` objects.
2. Append your new `Comment` to the collection.
3. **PUT** the new `Post` and its updated collection of `Comment` objects to that resource.

Worried about collisions? That's what [conditional operations](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/3.1.0.M1/reference/html/#conditional) are for, using standard HTTP headers. If you add a `@Version` based attribute to your `Post` domain object, then every time a given `Post` is updated with a new `Comment`, the version will increase.

When you **GET** the resource, Spring Data REST will include an E-Tag header.

That way, your **PUT** can be conditionalized with an HTTP **If-Match: <etag>** header. If someone else has updated the entity, you'll get back a 412 Status code, indicating you should refresh and try again.

NOTE: These conditional operations work for **PUT**, **PATCH**, and **DELETE** calls.