# add item to the collection with foreign key via REST call

Tags: java, json, rest, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have 2 jpa entities with bidirectional associasion.

Entity `Container` that holds collection of items (oneToMany)
Ommiting getter/setters

```
@javax.persistence.Entity
@Table(name = "CONTAINER")
public class Container implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3288335692695653843L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "container", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Item> items;

}
```

Entity `Item` contains reference back to the container (ManyToOne), with attributes value and date.
Ommiting setter/getters

```
@javax.persistence.Entity
@Table(name = "ITEM")
public class Item implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -758343957629274274L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @Basic
    private Long value;
    @Basic
    private Date date;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "CONTAINER_ID")
    private Container container;
}
```

Also i am using spring-data repositories to expose data.

My Interface repositories just extends `CrudRepository<Container, Long>` and `CrudRepository<Item, Long>`

```
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface ItemRepository extends CrudRepository<Item, Long> {
}

@RepositoryRestResource
public interface ContainerRepository extends CrudRepository<Container, Long> {
}
```

I am trying to create items via REST calls.

First i tried this on items repository `rest/items`

```
POST { "value" : 666, "date" : "2016-01-31T23:00:00.000+0000", "container": {"id":"1"}}
```

But it just creates item with null reference on container.

When i try to add via container repository `rest/containers/1/items`

```
POST { "value" : 666, "date" : "2016-01-31T23:00:00.000+0000", "container": {"id":"1"}}
```

I get `HTTP/1.1 204 No Content` and `<Response body is empty>`. No instance is created.

My question is how i can add item via REST call that has reference to the container.

EDIT: To specify my question, i want to add new item for the existing container. I am not sure how to deal with with foreign ID key when creating instance of Item via rest(json)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I resolved this issue by using link to the container inside json.

`POST { "value" : 666, "date" : "2016-01-31T23:00:00.000+0000","container":"http://localhost:8080/container/1"}`

I am not sure if it works without `spring-data-rest`

EDIT: I should point out, that linked resource has to be `@RepositoryRestResource` and should be **aggregate root**.

Comment: What should be json for posting in order to   save data to database  many to many lookup table,I Can't save object having many to many relationship using spring boot data rest.

Answer (score 0):

The http response status 204 is No Content. That is, the REST method you are calling is void and it doesn't return anything even if the instances ARE created.

Are you sure the instances are not created?, if they are not, post the code where they should be created so we can have a better idea of what's going on.

Comment: instances are not created via POST rest/containers/1/items
When i GET /rest/container/items, new instance is not listed. Neither when i list GET /rest/items.

Comment: Without the code creating the entities I can't say what's wrong. Edit the post including that code.