# Enable repository only for sub resource level in spring data rest?

Tags: rest, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I have 2 jpa entities Document and DispatchDetail which have one-to-many relationship. i.e. a document can have a list of dispatchDetails. I have created 2 repositories for each entity.

Now I'm gonna try a document GET.

```
http://localhost:7070/booking-documents-service/docs/5999571
```

---

```
{
    "docType": "SAP_ACCOUNTS_PAYABLE",
    "docStoreId": 456651,
    "qualityChecked": true,
    "format": "pdf",
    "bookingId": -1,
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:7070/booking-documents-service/docs/5999571"
        },
        "generatedDocument": {
            "href": "http://localhost:7070/booking-documents-service/docs/5999571"
        },
        "dispatchDetails": {
            "href": "http://localhost:7070/booking-documents-service/docs/5999571/dispatchDetails"
        }
    }
}
```

Now when I try GET request for the link listed as `dispatchDetails`. It is like this.

```
http://localhost:7070/booking-documents-service/docs/5999571/dispatchDetails
```

---

```
{
    "_embedded": {
        "dispatchDetails": [
            {
                "dispatchQueId": 207443,
                "dispatchStatus": "S",
                "recipient": "fldcvisla12678.wdw.disney.com|#|/opt/apps/shared/shuttle/SAP/OUT/|#|f-tbxshuttlenp|#|D1$NeY984|#|SFTP|#|22|#|null",
                "description": "Upload :FileUploadDispatcher; FTP:null/null;\n2d89df3d-ca51-4d35-9528-439923fa48d4..",
                "dispatcher": "AD",
                "_links": {
                    "self": {
                        "href": "http://localhost:7070/booking-documents-service/dispatchDetails/1"
                    },
                    "dispatchDetail": {
                        "href": "http://localhost:7070/booking-documents-service/dispatchDetails/1"
                    },
                    "generatedDocument": {
                        "href": "http://localhost:7070/booking-documents-service/dispatchDetails/1/generatedDocument"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:7070/booking-documents-service/docs/5999571/dispatchDetails"
        }
    }
}
```

But I don't want dispatch details as a stand alone resource (listed in links above).
i.e. I don't want this endpoint

```
http://localhost:7070/booking-documents-service/dispatchDetails
```

Instead I only need this.

```
http://localhost:7070/booking-documents-service/docs/5999571/dispatchDetails
```

How to achieve this? i.e. allow only sub resource level operations.