# Spring Data Rest and entities' IDs in relationships

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-rest

I'm working on a Spring Data Rest based Spring Boot service whose data model is similar to the one in the tutorial:
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-rest-relationships

(In defining the entities, I'm using Lombok annotations):

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "cale")
public class Book {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    private String title;

    @ManyToOne
    private Library library;

}


@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "library")
public class Library {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
    
    //...


}
```

invoking the endpoint `/books` I get the following json:

```
{
      "_embedded": {
        "books": [
          {
            "id": 22,
            "title": "The title of the book",
            "_links": {
              "self": {
                "href": "http://192.168.33.20:8080/books/22"
              },
              "book": {
                "href": "http://192.168.33.20:8080/books/22"
              },
              "library": {
                "href": "http://192.168.33.20:8080/books/22/library"
              }
            }
          },
          .
          .
          .
```

in HAL style, the only reference to the library linked to a given book is through an URL like `http://192.168.33.20:8080/books/22/library`

In order to get the id of the library associated to book 22, I have to perform a second GET call to the URL, which is inefficient in many cases.

Moreover, this makes it very hard to implement queries like "*GET all books associated to the library whose id is 101*".

Is there a way to let Spring Data Rest include also the id of the associated entity into the returned json? Something like:

```
{
      "_embedded": {
        "books": [
          {
            "id": 22,
            "title": "The title of the book",
            "library_id": 101, 
            "_links": {
            .
            .
            .
            }
          },
          .
          .
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a projection and use it by default with an excerpt.

To define the projection :

```
@Projection(
  name = "customBook", 
  types = { Book.class }) 
public interface CustomBook {
 
    @Value("#{target.id}")
    long getId(); 
    
    String getTitle();
    
    @Value("#{target.getLibrary().getId()}")
    int getLibraryId();
}
```

And call :

http://192.168.33.20:8080/books/22?projection=customBook

To use this projection by default configure your repo :

```
@RepositoryRestResource(excerptProjection = CustomBook.class)
public interface BookRepository extends CrudRepository<Book, Long> {}
```

Comment: it worked, thanks! do you know if there's some way to have it working also in POST (ie. including a `"libraryId": "1010"` in the JSON body when posting a new Book)?

Comment: Did you try something like this in your POST ? :
{"title": "book title","library": "http://192.168.33.20:8080:8080/library/1"}

Comment: it works (no error and the record gets created) but in the resulting record the field library_id is set to NULL (it seems the POST just ignores the "library" property)

Comment: I also tried `"_links": { "library": {
 "href": "http://192.168.33.20:8080/library/101" } },`: same behaviour

Comment: Did you have a look to this question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25311978/posting-a-onetomany-sub-resource-association-in-spring-data-rest?rq=1